# Filter with "&&" condition in array.filter()

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

So people i have 3 checkboxes:

```
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Java" id="check-java" class="check-java filled-in" 
                         />
                        <span>Java</span>
                    </label>
                    &nbsp;
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="JavaScript" id="check-javascript" class="check-javascript filled-in" />
                        <span>JavaScript</span>
                    </label>
                    &nbsp;
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Python" id="check-python" class="check-python filled-in"
                             />
                        <span>Python</span>
                    </label>
```

And when a user select this checkboxes i catch it in an eventListener`:

```
const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
checkBoxes.forEach((box) => {
    return box.addEventListener('change', filterByCheckBox)
});
```

So, when the user select two or more of this checkboxes i need to filter an array (devsFiltered), there contains a  sub-array called "programmingLanguages" and in this array i have 3 possible values "Java,JavaScript or Python" and i need to filter only if the array contains the two or more values selected by the checkboxes, the code i'm trying to use:

```
function filterByCheckBox(e) {
                const checkOption = e.target.value;
                if (devsFiltered.length > 0) {
                    const filtered  = devsFiltered
                    .filter(item => item.programmingLanguages
                        .every(lang => lang.language == checkOption));
                         mapUsers(filtered)
                }
        }
```

Comment: (1) Your `filtered` variable is a local variable, so your `filterByCheckBox` function has no effect. (2) It's not clear to me what you mean by "to filter only if [...]". Could you give an example where your code's behavior is not what you want, and explain what the behavior should be in that case?

Comment: Sorry about the radio, i try to simplify a little the code to post here and i dont notice i hasn't changed the addeventlistener, and the "filtered" i pass to a function as a parameter and there treat the data and pass load in the web page.

Comment: So you would beed to get all the checked checkboxes and not just the current one

Comment: @epascarello like an array of the selected checkboxes and one for loop to pass through the array and verify in .every()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get all the selections and you need to see if all the checked items are in the array.

```js
var people = [
 { name: "w", codes : ['a', 'b'] },
 { name: "x", codes : ['a', 'c'] },
 { name: "y", codes : ['a', 'b'] },
 { name: "z", codes : ['b','c'] }
];

var form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("change", function() {
  // get all the checked checkboxes
  const selections = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  // get all their values
  const values = selections && [...selections].map(({
    value
  }) => value);
  // filter the list to make sure all the values are in the object
  const filtered = values ?
    people.filter(({
        codes
      }) =>
      values.every(code => codes.includes(code))) : people;
      
  // Just to display something
  console.log(filtered.map(f => f.name).join(","));
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label for="a">A</label><input type="checkbox" id="a" value="a" />
  <label for="b">B</label><input type="checkbox" id="b" value="b" />
  <label for="c">C</label><input type="checkbox" id="c" value="c" />
</form>
```

in a format that is a bit more readable

You need to get all the selections and you need to see if all the checked items are in the array.

```js
var people = [
 { name: "w", codes : ['a', 'b'] },
 { name: "x", codes : ['a', 'c'] },
 { name: "y", codes : ['a', 'b'] },
 { name: "z", codes : ['b','c'] }
];

var form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("change", function() {

  let filtered = people;

  const selections = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  
  if (selections) {
    const values = [...selections].map(x => x.value);
    filtered = people.filter(person =>
      values.every(code => 
        person.codes.includes(code)
      )
    )
  }
      
  // Just to display something
  console.log(filtered.map(f => f.name).join(","));
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label for="a">A</label><input type="checkbox" id="a" value="a" />
  <label for="b">B</label><input type="checkbox" id="b" value="b" />
  <label for="c">C</label><input type="checkbox" id="c" value="c" />
</form>
```

Comment: So... I tried to implement your code on mine: 
function () { 
const selections = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]:checked'); 
if (selections) {
 const values = [...selections].map(x => x.value);
 const filtered = devsFiltered
.filter(item => values
.every(code => item.programmingLanguages.includes(code) ));
 console.log(filtered); } }) 

 But actually when passes by the "filtered" returns an empty array, i checked the devsFiltered and is fill.

Comment: To debug, I would need a basic object. Debug it with console.log and make sure you have values you expect.